# SapUI5 - extend controls - manage parent aggregations

Tags: controls, sapui5, aggregation, extend

Is possible to remove or add aggregations to parent control.

For example:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/StandardListItem"
], function(StandardListItem) {

return StandardListItem.extend("my.controls.CustomListItem", {
     metadata: {
         properties: {
             "name": 'string'
         },

         aggregations: {
             "nameIcon": {
                 type: "sap.ui.core.Icon",
                 multiple: false,
                 visibility: "hidden"
             },
```

Is possible to remove some element from parent(StandardListItem) or add nameIcon btw elements from StandardListItem ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove properties, associations, aggregations and events inherited from the base class. The baseclass aleady parsed its metadata and generated the accessors, fields etc in its prototype. Your class does the same and adds everything you define in the metadata to its prototype. 
You can however overwrite the asccessors (getXxx, setXxx, addYyy, removeYyy, attachZzz,...) of the baseclass and do nothing or throw an exception inside.

But you can add as many properties, associations, aggregations and events as you like. Just declare them in your metadata as you have done in your example.